# Change filenames while moving to another folder using unix shell script

Tags: regex, shell, command, filenames, mv

My issue is related to replacing filename while moving to target folder

```
echo "src_filename_final_array:::${src_filename_final_array[@]}"
```

displays following

```
SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.txt SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.ctl
```

The array `src_filename_final_array` contains the above two files.

have `mv` command written

```
mv "${src_filename_final_array[@]}" $src_file_InProcess_folder
```

is it possible in single `mv` command to change the file names `SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.txt SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.ctl` to  `SRC1_VEX_20190915.txt SRC1_VEX_20190915.ctl`

removal of version number it can be V4/v12/ or any starting V

Can anybody please suggest best way to do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: Please consider clarifying the question - also post what you have already tried

Comment: Hi Dash, src_filename_final_array is a array of filenames; it currently contains SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.txt SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.ctl (2 files). I would like to move these files in the array to target folder by removing the V part i.e. version part viz _V4 part.I have tried for loop of arraylist and one by one renamed file and moved it to target. but i would like to know whether there is any better one liner solution for it. Regards, Prasad  S Billahalli

Comment: Usually, it is better to post what yu have already implemented. This will save everybody time, not having to duplicate effort. Consider editing the question to include the details that you provided in the comment, and your current solution(s)

Comment: Hi Sungtm, Thanks for formatting the question. next time would take care. Regards, Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple script to loop through the array and change each file name
as shown below

```
src_filename_final_array=(SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.txt SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.ctl)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   new_file=`echo "$i" | sed 's/V[0-9]_//g'`
   mv "$i" "$new_file"

done
```

Below is working example

```
[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ ls -lrt
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 cloudera cloudera 4096 Oct 31 00:17 sub2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera  177 Oct 31 23:41 table_list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera    0 Nov  3 23:30 SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera    0 Nov  3 23:31 SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.ctl
```

After :

```
[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ for i in "${arr[@]}"
> do
>    new_file=`echo "$i" | sed 's/V[0-9]_//g'`
>    mv "$i" "$new_file"
> 
> done
[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ ls -lrt
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 cloudera cloudera 4096 Oct 31 00:17 sub2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera  177 Oct 31 23:41 table_list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera    0 Nov  3 23:30 SRC1_VEX_20190915.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera cloudera    0 Nov  3 23:31 SRC1_VEX_20190915.ctl
```

Comment: Hello Strick.. thanks for your response. This was one option, wanted to check whether there was any single line command to do so. Meanwhile have implemented the solution you provided.. it works neat and clean. Thanks again Warm regards, Prasad

Comment: @pbillaha: if it solves your question can you please upvote and mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider using 'rename' (from the perl contributed package), which has strong RE capabilities, building on the Perl engine.

```
rename 's/V[0-9]_//g' SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.txt SRC1_VEX_V4_20190915.ctl
```

Please check to make sure that you have the correct `rename` code. It is part of the `rename` package, and is sometimes distributed as `file-rename`

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. it helped